# FlowDocumentScrollViewer does not display text (WPF, XAML)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, flowdocument, flowdocumentscrollviewer

I have xaml with button and FlowDocumentScrollViewer:

```
<Button Content="My Button" Command="{Binding SomeButton}"/>
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer Document="{Binding FlowDocument}"/>
```

Now I want into VM add some logic:

```
private ICommand m_SomeButtonCommand ;
public ICommand SomeButton => m_SomeButtonCommand ?? (m_SomeButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(RunSM, true));

private void RunSM
{
  FlowDocument flowDocument = new FlowDocument();
  Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(new Run("some new Text"));

  paragraph.Background = Brushes.White;
  paragraph.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
  paragraph.FontSize = 14;

  m_flowDocumentScrollViewer = new FlowDocumentScrollViewer();
  m_flowDocumentScrollViewer.Document = flowDocument;
}

private FlowDocumentScrollViewer m_flowDocumentScrollViewer;

public FlowDocumentScrollViewer FlowDocumentScrollViewer
{
  get
  {
    return m_flowDocumentScrollViewer;
  }
  set
  {
    if (m_flowDocumentScrollViewer == value)
     return;

     m_flowDocumentScrollViewer = value;
    OnPropertyChanged();
  }
 }

 private FlowDocument m_flowDocument;
 public FlowDocument FlowDocument
    {
        get
        {
            return m_flowDocument;
        }

        set
        {
            if (m_flowDocument == value)
                return;

            m_flowDocument = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

But nothing is display.

Comment: Your RunSM method does not assign a value to the FlowDocument property. Instead, it assigns the Document property of a private FlowDocumentScrollViewer instance, which does not make any sense. Remove it from the view model. Moreover, RunSM does not even add the Paragraph to the FlowDocument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First of all**, you should not declare property for `FlowDocumentScrollViever` inside your ViewModel - it is already backed with a field inside compiler generated CodeBehind partial class (your xaml.cs sibling).

**Second**, instead of instantiating local variable in your `RunSM()` method, you could directly instantiate your `FlowDocument` property, like this:

```
private void RunSM()
{
    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(new Run("some new Text"));

    paragraph.Background = Brushes.White;
    paragraph.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
    paragraph.FontSize = 14;

    ///note that im passing previously created paragraph, because the ONLY way to do it is through the constructor
    FlowDocument = new FlowDocument(paragraph);
}
```

Now, assuming your `INotifyPropertyChanged` is implemented properly (`RaisePropertyChanged()` call in `FlowDocument` setter), it should automatically notify UI with the changes, because `FlowDocument` property is already bound with your `FlowDocumentScrollViewer`:

```
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer Document="{Binding FlowDocument}"/>
```

**Third**, you should never set a value to your property's backing field directly when outside of it's (property) setter!

So, instead of `m_flowDocument = foo;`, you should rather write `FlowDocument = foo;`.

P.S. Correct me if im wrong, but the prefixed syntax (e.g. m_, s_) is no longer up to current C# naming conventions, so it's recommended not to use this, except in case when project convention enforces it.